# Sort order in get_posts

Tags: query, get-posts, wp-reset-postdata

I've created a [custom template](http://health.gov.ie/policy/) for a client. This is going to be a multilingual site setup on a Multisite install.

As you can see under each category letter, the posts start out in alphabetical order but "M" and "O" are all out of whack.

If you click through onto those categories, using the alphabet bar at the top, those posts are in alphabetical order.

Both pages are using the same code, so I've no idea what I'm doing wrong. I have a feeling I have a query conflict somewhere but I can't find it. Here's the code that does the sorting:

```
<section class="atozlist">
    <?php
        $newargs = array(
            'child_of'  => $catID,
            'order'     => 'ASC'
            );
        $categories =  get_categories($newargs);
        foreach  ($categories as $category) {
            echo '<h2>'.$category->name.'</h2>';
            echo '<ul>';

            $titleArgs = array(
                'cat'       => $category->term_id,
                'order_by'  => 'title',
                'order'     => 'ASC'
                );
            foreach (get_posts($titleArgs) as $post) {
                setup_postdata( $post );
                echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>'; 
            } 
            wp_reset_postdata();
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    ?>
</section>
```

I'm unsure about the implementation of [`setup_postdata($post)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata#Example_1), though I used this as a template. I'm also unsure if I've implemented `wp_reset_postdata()` correctly.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Where and how is `$catID` defined

Comment: Set previously as the current category of this page.

Comment: Then your code is fine then

Comment: order_by... should be orderby. Dammit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah yeah... we all missed the `order_by`, didn't we... Should be `orderby`.

Dammit.

Thanks for the help everyone anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not that the posts that are being wrongly displayed are displayed under the wrong category, it's that they're not actually *in* the right category. For example, the post "Supporting healthy eating choices" is displayed under "O" as it has the category "O". Going to your backend and assigning the proper category to these posts should fix it. In short, there's nothing wrong with your code, some of your posts just belong to the wrong categories.

Comment: I thought that, but, even though the posts are in the incorrect category, the titles should still sort alphabetically. If you look at "M" on the "ALL" page for example. All those post titles start with "M", yet "Mental Health" appears last. The actual titles in the wrong categories is another issue I need to deal with with the client, but this is definitely an issue in my code.